# Executing binary files with a shebang

Tags: binaryfiles, chmod, ubuntu-11.10, gedit, shebang

I created a simple program that takes the path of a directory as an input, creates an archive of that directory (converting it into a single file), adds a shebang to that file (so that the contents of the file can be easily extracted), and writes the file to the base directory of the specified path.

The problem is that the file does not extract itself when I double click on it. Instead the operating system (I'm using Ubuntu 11.10) tries to open it with gedit. This obviously shows the shebang, random gibberish, and the contents of the archived files.

I made the file executable, first by using `chmod +x`; and when it still didn't work I tried `chmod 777`. However it still refuses to execute the file with the shebang when I double click on it. Perhaps this is because it's not a pure text file.

Interestingly when I try to execute the file directly from command line it reads the shebang and extracts the contents of the archive properly. So there's nothing wrong with my file format. I don't know much about what operating systems do when you double click on a file but I would sure like to understand.

It surely makes no sense to add a shebang to a file if you still need to manually execute it from the command line. One advantage could be that you don't need to specify the program to open it with but I believe that's hardly an advantage. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update 1:**

The program that creates the archive is called **opm**. It can be installed via the **node package manager** using the following command:

```
npm install opm
```

After that you simply use **opm** to pack and unpack directories for you. For example if I have a directory called `test` in my home directory then I can open a terminal and execute the following command to pack it:

```
opm test
```

This will create an archive of the directory called `test.pack` in the home directory. The `.pack` file has the shebang `#!/usr/bin/opm`. Opening a file with the extension `.pack` with **opm** tells it that it's an archive and **opm** unpacks it in the same directory.

**Note:** Change the name of the `test.pack` file if you do not want it to overwrite your existing `test` directory.

I added the shebang to  the `.pack` file so that it would extract itself when I opened it. However that doesn't seem to work. Nevertheless if I run one of the following command then it works:

```
./test.pack
```

You may check my source code and make any modifications to the program as you may wish to.

**Update 2:**

Alright I created the following `.desktop` file for **opm** and stored it in the `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` directory:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=OPM
GenericName=Object Packer and Minifier
NoDisplay=true
Comment=JavaScript Package Manager
TryExec=opm
Exec=opm %f
Terminal=false
MimeType=application/opm
```

Now I was able to associate `.pack` files with **opm** by right clicking on a `.pack` file, going to the `Properties` window, the `Open With` tab, and setting `opm.desktop` as the default application. Now I am able to unpack a `.pack` file by simply opening it.

However I would like to know how to associate `.pack` files with the mime type `application/opm`. Currently the `.pack` files are associated with `application/x-java-pack200`. How do I do so? Is it better if I use a different extension (e.g. `.opm`)? By associating the packed archives with the mime type `application/opm` will the OS open them with **opm** by default without having to explicitly set a default application from `Properties > Open With`?

Comment: Alright so I went to the properties of the file. I went to the Opens With tab and reset it so that it now doesn't open with gedit. However when I try to execute the file by double clicking on it now it says `Could not display. The file is of an unknown type.` Why's Ubuntu trying to display the file? When I go to `Edit > Preferences > Behaviour` in my File Manager it shows me that Ubuntu must ask me to either run or view executable text files every time I open them. I know that my file's an executable. I think the problem is that it's not a text file. The MIME type's `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Can you post the shebang, and the file extension ?

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro - I edited my question as per your request.

Comment: Can you associate `.pack` files with `opm`?  This way the operating system will invoke opm with the file passed as an argument when you double-click, just like you would in a command line (`opm test.pack`)

Comment: @Attila - I managed to associate `.pack` files with `opm`. How may I change the mime type of `.pack` files?

Comment: I am not that familiar with ubuntu, but check out Erik Kruus's answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66524/why-cant-i-make-a-file-association-in-nautilus) and [this article](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mimetypes-modifying.html.en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's already a MIME-type associated with .pack then you'll want to use a different extension (.opm) to associate with your MIME-type (application/opm).  The way you automatically associate a program that opens files of a specific MIME-type is with [xdg-mime](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/xdg-mime.1.html) .

Alternatively,

- Edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and put your MIME/application combo under [Default Applications] like so:

> ```
> [Default Applications]
> application/opm=opm.desktop;
> ```

- Place your `opm.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` folder. (You've already done this)